# Can not connect to BLE device from Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a system which there are two application: first is an application on Android, second is an application run on Linux. They must communicate via BLE protocol

On Linux, i have modified a code of Bluez 4.1(btgattserver.c). The application on Linux will broadcast BLE advertiser package, and wait connect from Android.

On Android, i am using this API to connect to Linux application:

`public BluetoothGatt connectGatt (Context context, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback callback)`

My problem is: on Android 5, these applications can communicate normally. But on Android 4.4.2, the Android application can not connect to Linux application

I have turned on option "Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop" on Android and got the log file of HCI on Android 5. and android 4.4.2 to compare.

I found that on Android 5., the request connect has PSM which is SDP, but the request connect on Android 4.4.2 has PSM which is ATT. And the connection on Android 4.4.2 was rejected by Linux application (Please see my attached image)
[image]
Please tell my why Android 4.4.2 create connect request with PSM is ATT? And how to resolve this problem?

Because my English is not good, so im sorry if my question make you difficult to understand.

Thanks you.

Comment: The minimum requirement for BLE support is Android 4.3 (API 18).

Comment: thank for your comment. We are using Android 4.4